# Dynamic Populate Text Field in APEX

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I am trying to do an auto population of a form text-field in APEX using another database table as follows:

Table 1: `TSTPAY` (FORM Write)

```
ID (Sequence)
EMP_ID
BU_ID
AMOUNT
```

Table 2: `EMBU`

```
EMP | A
BU  | BU_A
```

Basically I am looking for the APEX form to behave in such a way that when the user inputs 'A' into the the EMP_ID text field, it will trigger an action to pre-populate the BU_ID to BU_A.

The action I've created does not appear to be resolving any value for :P7_EMPID. I can see the action working where I've hard coded in the 'Where' value into my SQL statement (i.e. `SELECT BU FROM BUEMP A WHERE A.EMP = 'A'`)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Full implementation details below:

Using some resources I've built a dynamic action to trigger on change of the P7_EMPID.
-Sequence:10
-When Event: Change, Selection type items: P7_EMPID, EVENT SCOPE STATIC

SET VALUE
-Action: set value, set type: SQL statement, page items to submit: P7_BU, escape special characters: no, supress change event: no, affected elements: items, affected element item: P7_BU, fire when event result is true, fire on page load: true, wait for result: true.

The SQL query used is:

```
SELECT A.BU
FROM BUEMP A
WHERE A.EMP = :P7_EMPID
```

Comment: Is the table named BUEMP or EMBU or something else?

Comment: The table being written to with the form is tstpay. Empbu is the table used as a look up to automatically derive the BU based on the user input of the emp_id

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are submitting P7_BU while your code requires P7_EMPID.
try submitting P7_EMPID instead..